# Podman: automatic network rules and iptables

Tags: networking, iptables, firewalld, podman

When I run podman container and share port 4444 as following example:

```
podman run -dit --name test -p 4444:4444 alpine
```

It creates following iptable

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
NETAVARK_FORWARD  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* netavark firewall plugin rules */

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain NETAVARK_FORWARD (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.88.0.0/16         ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  10.88.0.0/16         anywhere
```

**Question:** 
Is there a way to prevent podman from creating any firewall rules automatically? 
For above example I have used:

- Rocky Linux 9.1
- Podman v 4.2.1
- Firewalld 1.1.1
- iptables v1.8.8 (nf_tables)